# Flask Socket io is inconsistent with connection (uwsgi+nginx)

Tags: nginx, flask, socket.io, uwsgi, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I am running my socket on my local machine(development server) it is working perfectly.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=2000, app=app)
```

Although when I deployed the same on a server using UWSGI and reverse proxy using NGINX, the connection response is returned as BAD REQUEST(400). The connection gets established for sometime though but is very inconsistent.

I checked the error in nginx logs and found out the error "**upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream**". I have been struggling with this error for quite some time. It would be great if someone could help me out of this mess :/

**P.S. Tell me if any other kind of logs are required to further investigate**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my problem. Although it is not very elaborate but it is what it is. Since most of the sample examples had described taking **workers as 3**, I was deploying mine with the same configuration but that was resulting in prematurely closing the connection, I assume this could have been because the server was not capable of running multiple workers together. So what I did was, I reduced the **workers to 1** and implemented gevent on top of it. The command looked something like following(using gunicorn):

`gunicorn -k gevent -w 1 module:app`

---

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with nginx + flask + uwsgi + socketio.
Finally I fixed it with the following configuration.

in config ini file,

```
master=false
processes=1 # set the process as 1, which fixed socket connection issue
enable-threads=true # instead, enabled threads
threads=5
```

Hope it helps others save time.